# vertex shaders vs vertex

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have a question - I am learning OpenGL ES 2.0 from this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) and moving across this website, I have build nice app, with spinning polygon. 
I find another [guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial) where he used vertex shaders. What are the differences between them. What else I can make with shaders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that the first tutorial uses OpenGL ES 1.1, and the second uses OpenGL ES 2.0. 1.1 used the fixed-function pipeline to do all of its rendering, while 2.0 exclusively uses shaders.

All of those matrix functions? glLoadIdentity, glFrustum, glRotate? They're gone in 2.0. Instead, you write a program (shader) that executes on the GPU itself. The shader responsible for transforming vertex positions is called the "vertex shader".

So the vertex shader replaces all of the automatic matrix transforms with a much more flexible, user-driven, computation system.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, OpenGL ES 1.1 is (much) easier to get into, while OpenGL ES 2.0 is much more flexible and probably potentially a lot faster. There are some things you just can't do in 1.1.

OpenGL ES 1.1 and 2.0 are completely mutually incompatible, so choose wisely.

There is much more material out there to learn 1.1 than there is for 2.0.

Comment: I disagree on ES 1.1 being much easier to get into. A lot of people talk about how the fixed-function pipeline is easier to use, but I don't see it. It's certainly easier to throw something on the screen, but throwing _something_ on the screen is not what a graphics programmer does. Graphics programmers have to throw a _particular_ thing on the screen. And shaders are the easiest way to put what you _want_ on the screen.

Comment: Maybe I'm biased because I learnt fixed-function before learning shaders. Anyway, to the OP: If you have a developer account, look into the iOS 5 beta versions. I haven't tried this particular framework, but I've heard there is now something called `GLKit` or so that apparently simplifies setup (which can be quite a bitch on iOS - even getting perspective projection is not easy with GLES2 when you don't really know what you're doing). Apparently Instruments also now has better OpenGL debug tools.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of it, Vertices are representations of points on the 3D things you render, while Vertex Shaders are a means to temporarily modify a Vertex before rendering. Vertex Shaders run on your video card (gpu), so you can perform many actions in parallel (e.g. perform the same function on all of the vertices in your scene)- this takes a lot of burden off of your cpu.